# PHP & regexp - исключить некоторые расширения файлов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, файлы, extension

Есть список файлов, и мне нужно исключить файлы с некоторыми расширениями, например картинки.
Вот у меня есть выражение, но я никак не могу его добить:

```
/\b([a-z0-9.-]+\.[^(?:jp(?:e?g|e|2)|gif|png|tiff?|bmp|ico)$][a-z0-9.-]+)\b/i
```

Он исключает например, **png**, но уже **pnga** или что-то подобное уже не пропускает.

Comment: В каком виде у вас хранится список файлов?

Comment: Просто массив с именами файлов, без путей.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу способа сделать целиком на регулярке, но можно в три шага (две регулярки и разность массивов):

```
$list = '
test1.png
test2.pnga
test3.jpg
test4.doc
test4.doc1
';

$pattern_all = '/^([a-z0-9.-]+)\s*/im';
preg_match_all($pattern_all, $list, $all_files);

$pattern_bad = '/^([a-z0-9.-]+\.(jpg|png|gif))\s*/im';
preg_match_all($pattern_bad, $list, $bad_files);

$needed_files = array_diff($all_files[1], $bad_files[1]);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, в два этапа точно помогло!!!

Comment: По каким-то причинам другой пользователь использовал начало моего ответа в своём и вы, видимо, ошибочно подняли его ответ вверх. Рад, что разбивка на упрощённые действия помогла.

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = '
test1.png
test2.pnga
test3.jpg
test4.doc
test4.doc1
';

/\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.bmp|\.doc|\.doc1|\.pnga$/

| - или.
\. - экранируем точку в имени файла (image.png)
jpg|png|jpeg - или jpg, или png или jpeg.. и так далее, все через ИЛИ (|)
```

Если в проверяемой строке будет окончание на .формат (image.png) тогда при preg_match будет true

Comment: Спасибо большое, в два этапа точно помогло!!!

Comment: @user2007024, а регулярка тут неправильная. Она среагирует и на `fff.png`, и на `fff.0png`, например.

Comment: Поправил, ступил малость.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую прочитать [официальное руководство](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Вы можете сделать png по примеру tiff из Вашей же регулярки. Примерно так:

```
/\b([a-z0-9.-]+\.[^(?:jp(?:e?g|e|2)|gif|pnga?|tiff?|bmp|ico)$][a-z0-9.-]+)\b/i
```

Метасимвол ? означает что символ перед ним может быть, а может не быть.